# How can I empose the ntree parameter into the train() function of caret package?

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, r-caret

I am using the following function to do cross-validation with the random forest algorithm on my dataset. However, ntree raises an error, saying that it is not used in the function. Even though I have seen that usage as a recommendation comment before in one of the threads regarding this issue, it did not work at me. Here is my code:

```
cv_rf_class1 <- train(y_train_u ~ ., x_train_u , 
                      method ="cforest", 
                      trControl = trainControl(method = "cv", 
                                               number = 10, 
                                               verboseIter = TRUE),  
                                               ntree = 100))
```

If I cannot change the ntree parameter, it uses 500 trees as default in the function and it raises another error for me (subscript out of bounds), so I cannot make it work for my problem. How can I fix this issue in order to make my function work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ntree` needs to be an argument of `train`, and not of `trainControl` as you have used it here; from the documentation of [`train`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/4.47/topics/train):

> **...**
>   arguments passed to the classification or regression routine (such as [`randomForest`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/link/randomForest?package=caret&version=4.47&to=randomForest)). Errors will occur if values for tuning parameters are passed here.

Notice also that you are not passing the data in the correct form; `train` expects the data as `(x, y)`, and not as you are passing them (an incorrect combination of formula and matrices).

All in all, change your `train` call to:

```
cv_rf_class1 <- train(x_train_u, y_train_u,
                      method ="cforest", 
                      ntree = 100,
                      trControl = trainControl(method = "cv", 
                                               number = 10, 
                                               verboseIter = TRUE))
```

**UPDATE** (after comments)

Well, it seems that `cforest` in particular will not accept an `ntree` argument, because, in contrast with the original `randomForest` package, this is *not* how you pass the number of trees in the underlying `cforest` function of the respective package ([docs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/party/versions/1.3-3/topics/cforest)).

The correct way, as demonstrated in the relevant examples in the [`caret` Github repo](https://github.com/topepo/caret/blob/master/RegressionTests/Code/cforest.R), is:

```
cv_rf_class1 <- train(x_train_u, y_train_u,
                      method ="cforest", 
                      trControl = trainControl(method = "cv", 
                                               number = 10, 
                                               verboseIter = TRUE),
                      controls = party::cforest_unbiased(ntree = 100))
```

Adapting [`cforest.R`](https://github.com/topepo/caret/blob/master/RegressionTests/Code/cforest.R), we get:

```
library(caret)
library(plyr)
library(recipes)
library(dplyr)

model <- "cforest"

set.seed(2)
training <- twoClassSim(50, linearVars = 2)
testing <- twoClassSim(500, linearVars = 2)
trainX <- training[, -ncol(training)]
trainY <- training$Class

rec_cls <- recipe(Class ~ ., data = training) %>%
  step_center(all_predictors()) %>%
  step_scale(all_predictors())

seeds <- vector(mode = "list", length = nrow(training) + 1)
seeds <- lapply(seeds, function(x) 1:20)

cctrl1 <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 3, returnResamp = "all",
                       classProbs = TRUE, 
                       summaryFunction = twoClassSummary,
                       seeds = seeds)

set.seed(849)
test_class_cv_model <- train(trainX, trainY, 
                             method = "cforest", 
                             trControl = cctrl1,
                             metric = "ROC", 
                             preProc = c("center", "scale"),
                             controls = party::cforest_unbiased(ntree = 20)) # WORKS OK

test_class_pred <- predict(test_class_cv_model, testing[, -ncol(testing)])
test_class_prob <- predict(test_class_cv_model, testing[, -ncol(testing)], type = "prob")

head(test_class_pred)
# [1] Class2 Class2 Class2 Class1 Class1 Class1
# Levels: Class1 Class2

head(test_class_prob)
#      Class1    Class2
# 1 0.4996686 0.5003314
# 2 0.4333222 0.5666778
# 3 0.3625118 0.6374882
# 4 0.5373396 0.4626604
# 5 0.6174159 0.3825841
# 6 0.5327283 0.4672717
```

Output of `sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                            LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] recipes_0.1.7   dplyr_0.8.3     plyr_1.8.4      caret_6.0-84    ggplot2_3.2.1   lattice_0.20-38
```